# Forcing HTTP redirect to HTTPS is ignoring subdomains

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl, https

I have set up a Apache server with the 3 virtual hosts `tomrouse.me`, `dev.tomrouse.me` and `server.tomrouse.me`. All of the virtual hosts worked fine. When I went to each one, it would take me to the index for that site.

But when I added SSL and forced HTTP to redirect to HTTPS, it is now always going to the `tomrouse.me` virtual host no matter what subdomain I request.

Files I have in available sites in Apache:

[image]

SSL configuration for Apache:

[image]

I dont think it is a issue with the virtual hosts, as all were working fine until I added SSL with redirects using the `python-letsencrypt-apache` program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fixed, i went wrong by trying to install the ssl in all sub domains at once did a full reinstall then did each one one at a time and it works fine!

For example:

This is what it tells you to do (this will not work):

```
sudo letsencrypt --apache -d tomrouse.me -d dev.tomrouse.me -d server.tomrouse.me
```

I reinstalled the server the same but did this part like this:

```
sudo letsencrypt --apache -d tomrouse.me
sudo letsencrypt --apache -d dev.tomrouse.me
sudo letsencrypt --apache -d server.tomrouse.me
```

and selected the force https like i did before for each this is a fix if you have the same issie however if you already did it the first way you have to restart as far as i know i tryed doing this after the first way and it dint work.

[Correct format of apache config files:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09KhS.png)

All of the ssl config files should be created by the lets encrypted program https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04